# Design on Web Services in Blackberry Cascades application

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I am (trying) to write a Cascades application that includes many calls to various Web Services. I have got this working fine in my main Application class but I would like to be able to call another class - a Services Manager class if you will - and get it to return a value to my calling Application class when the service call has been processed by the Services Manager class and has completed.

Is this a good design? This is the route I would take in Java but I am completely new to C++ and QT.  Could I potentially use an emit and signal process to produce this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if I read your question correctly.

It's entirely reasonable for the ServicesManager class to communicate with the Application class via signals / slots. It kind of sounds like these are running in different threads, but that's fine with Qt signals/slots. Also, you can subclass the signal class to send a custom payload (or just tell the receiver "hey, I'm done, query me for the results").

If async is what you want, have a look at this pretty good explanation:

[Qt Signals/Slots across Threads](http://cdumez.blogspot.com/2011/03/worker-thread-in-qt-using-signals-slots.html)

Comment: @user1754529: I started to wonder if the explanation I pointed you to is overly-complex for what you want. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html for a more straightforward explanation directly from the Qt developers. (Jump down about 2/3 to "Signals and Slots Across Threads" - I think a "blocking" or "queued" connection is what your after depending on whether you want sync or async for your app, respectively).